# How do I prevent NaN from appearing in the drupal form field?

Tags: forms

For this field, if a user enters a space and leaves the field, the field fills with NaN, any idea how I can prevent that from happening?

```
if (variable_get('variable', DEFAULT) === 1) {
$basics_form['number_of_things'] = array(
  '#type'          => 'textfield',
  '#title'         => t('Number of things'),
  '#description'   => t('How many of this thing are there?'),
  '#size'          => 5,
  '#required'      => FALSE,
  '#attributes'    => array('class' => 'basics-tab__input--small'),
  '#prefix'        => '<div class="basics-tab__number">',
  '#suffix'        => '</div>',
  '#default_value' => isset($v->field_number[0]['value']) ? $v->field_number[0]['value'] : NULL,
);
```

}

Comment: Can you not use textfield and use type number instead ? or if you want to use textfield you can use client-side js validation to check whether its a number or not.

Comment: Changing the type to number does work, but it strips out all my attributes around the input field for some reason...